# Nothing show in table when reload the table on text change

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsurlconnection, uisearchbar

I have a search bar in which user can filter user name.The string enter by the user that post to the server and responds with an array of users that got filtered. I am trying to load those users into the table view and when the user changes the search item it goes through the same process -

```
#import "AddFriend.h"


@implementation AddFriend

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
}
*/

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    _searchBar.delegate = self;
    searchResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    myTableView.dataSource = self;
    myTableView.delegate = self;
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

        [searchResults removeAllObjects];
         _searchString = searchBar.text;
        [self postSearch];
}

-(void)postSearch{

    // Create the request.
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/search"]];

    // Specify that it will be a POST request
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

    // This is how we set header fields
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    // Convert your data and set your request's HTTPBody property
    NSDictionary *parameters = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                _searchString, @"username",
                                nil];
    NSError *error;
    NSData *postdata = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:0 error:&error];
    [request setHTTPBody:postdata];

    // Create url connection and fire request
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [connection start];
}

#pragma mark - NSURL Methods
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    // A response has been received, this is where we initialize the instance var you created
    // so that we can append data to it in the didReceiveData method
    // Furthermore, this method is called each time there is a redirect so reinitializing it
    // also serves to clear it
    _responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    // Append the new data to the instance variable you declared
    [_responseData appendData:data];
}

- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
                  willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse*)cachedResponse {
    // Return nil to indicate not necessary to store a cached response for this connection
    return nil;
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    // The request is complete and data has been received
    // You can parse the stuff in your instance variable now

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization
                     JSONObjectWithData:_responseData
                     options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                     error:&error];

    for (int i = 0; i < json.count; i++) {
        NSDictionary *resultsDictionary = [json objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *username = [resultsDictionary objectForKey:@"username"];
        [searchResults addObject:username];
    }
        NSLog(@"%@", searchResults);
    [myTableView reloadData];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [searchResults count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    if (searchResults.count > 1) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    return cell;

}
@end
```

Comment: what is your exact problem?Not getting from your question.

Comment: nothing is showing up in the table

Comment: try to print json array i think it is dictionary not array

Comment: im getting the data ok its not adding to the table

Comment: put the breakpoint in cellForRowAtIndexPath and check the data is come or not?

Comment: and give [cell.textLable setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]] in if(cell == nil)

Answer (score 1):

check

> ```
>     NSLog(@"%@", searchResults);
> ```

what are you getting there?
also, every time you do a refresh of the data after search, you should clear your results array

> [searchResults removeAllObjects]

Comment: i get the usernames , i did try to clear them in textdidchange